# Java Apache HTTP error: Receiving CRLF expected at end of chunk

Tags: java, mule

While reading XML response as a string using HTTP Apache client I am receiving the following exception:

```
org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: CRLF expected at end of chunk
```

This is to read XML retrieved from REST API in my code:

```
{WebTarget target = this.client.target(new URI(loginUrl));
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Entity.entity(xmlString, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
logger.info("Response -> "+response);
String responseXML = response.readEntity(String.class);}
```

This response is triggered at random intervals by the server.

```
HTTP Request 
POST http://{serverName}:{port}/auth/2.8/signin

HTTP Response
An Apache HTTP Response Pojo Object
```

Comment: Please clarify how is this question related to the mule tag and add reproduction steps, and the HTTP request/response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help to identify and address this issue.

There is insufficient information in your question to do that.

The client library is complaining the response it go is malformed; i.e. it violates the HTTP specification.  The particular part of the spec that it is talking about is [Section 4.1 - Chunked Transfer Coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1)

One possible explanation is that the web server you are trying to use has been implemented incorrectly.  This might happen if you are using a server that some misguided person has tried to implement from the ground up using sockets ... rather than the sensible approach which is to use an existing web container or http protocol library.

A second possible explanation is something is interfering with the TCP / HTTP data in flight.  For example, this apparently used to happen with some older versions of the Android Emulator when talking to a webserver via an MS proxy; see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36919648

How to investigate this?  Well I would suggest the following:

1. Read the relevant part of the HTTP specification so that you understand what to look for.
2. Use a packet monitoring tool such as Wireshark to capture the raw traffic for one of these failures.
3. Examine the captured packets carefully for spot the missing CRLF
4. Work out where the packet is coming from, and work back to the source to see where the problem is being generated.

Also, look through some of the other "CRLF expected at end of chunk" Q&As for ones that seem relevant for your case.